# blazor - drag drop setDragImage

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can we change the object that is dragged in blazor? I found the [following example](https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html) for html5/js. However I don't know how to do this in blazor without going full js interrupt. The `DragEventArgs` object seems to be missing this `setDragImage()` function.

Html/JS code from example:

```
<div id="drag-coveredup" class="dragdemo" draggable="true">drag me</div>
<div id="coverup"></div>
<style>
#coverup {
    background: white;
    width: 170px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
</style>
<script>
document.getElementById("drag-coveredup").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
    var crt = this.cloneNode(true);
    crt.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    crt.style.position = "absolute"; crt.style.top = "0px"; crt.style.right = "0px";
    document.body.appendChild(crt);
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
}, false);
</script>
```

Edit: [Microsoft refers to custom events](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33158)

Edit2: I know how to create a custom event, but how can I call the function `.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0)` from this custom event? I can only find examples with properties.

I created the following customEvent.js file

```
function CustomDragEventCreator(event) {
    return {
        ...parseMouseEvent(event),
        dataTransfer: event.dataTransfer ? {
            dropEffect: event.dataTransfer.dropEffect,
            effectAllowed: event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed,
            files: Array.from(event.dataTransfer.files).map(f => f.name),
            items: Array.from(event.dataTransfer.items).map(i => ({ kind: i.kind, type: i.type })),
            types: event.dataTransfer.types,
            setDragImage(image, x, y) {
                console.writeln("Hello from CustomDragEventCreator.dataTransfer.setDragImage");
                event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(image, x, y);
            }
        } : null,
    };
}
```

This has the following cs file

```
public class CustomDragEventArgs : MouseEventArgs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The data that underlies a drag-and-drop operation, known as the drag data store.
    /// See <see cref="DataTransfer"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomDataTransfer DataTransfer { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

CustomDataTransfer.cs:

```
public class CustomDataTransfer : DataTransfer
{
    public void SetDragImage(object image, int x, int y)
    {
        //How to get this working?
    }
}
```

And added the EventHandler:

```
[EventHandler("onCustomDragStart", typeof(CustomDragEventArgs), enableStopPropagation: true, enablePreventDefault: true)]
public static class EventHandlers
{
}
```

And on index.html:

```
<script>
    Blazor.registerCustomEventType('customevent', {
        createEventArgs: CustomDragEventCreator
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with using JsRuntime. It works, but is probably not ideal for big drag/drop lists.

xxx.js:

```
function addCustomListener(elementId, html)
{
    document.getElementById(elementId).addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
        let crt = this.cloneNode(true);
        crt.style.position = "absolute"; crt.style.top = "auto"; crt.style.left = "-10000px";
        crt.innerHTML = html;
        document.body.appendChild(crt);
        e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(crt, 0, 0);
    }, false);
}
```

xxx.razor.cs

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addCustomListener",$"{Setup.StylingId}", Setup.HtmlContent);
        }
    }
```